# iSight cable for mid 2009 macbook pro 13" help

Tags: macbook-pro, webcam

If my iSight camera no longer works and neither does my bluetooth, should my wifi still technically be working? Aren't they all co-dependent(if that makes sense) or can the fact that my wifi is still functional mean that the iSight camera still works and it's a software problem.

Comment: There is not necessary relationship between your iSight not working and your Wifi, but... there *could* be since the antenna is in the hinge or lid, depending on your model. Is your Wifi working and you think it shouldn't, or is it not working and you think it is related? You might have a worn internal cable and [servicing the camera](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Replacing+MacBook+Core+2+Duo+iSight/4771/1) could take care of both problems.

Comment: I kinda wanted to clarify that relationship between the two. Because I wanted to try and disconnect and reconnect the cable from the motherboard and I wash't sure if I did my wifi would stop working.

Comment: Forgive the comments - I missed the title and hope you don't mind the undelete. Flag this if you really want it gone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in step 20 of the take apart guide from iFixit, the camera cable and wireless card are one and the same cable.

- http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Replacing+MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2009+AirPort+Card/6019/3#s26379

Getting the clutch cover off the display assembly is a bit tricky even for trained technicians and the cable routing is something you will want to be nimble and intentional when removing the connectors from the logic board and especially when repairing parts in the display.

I would say you could rule out software quite easily without taking your Mac apart by just installing a clean OS onto an external drive or USB storage device (be patient if your USB is slow). You could also reseat the cables on the logic board and inspect for damage there without too much harm of breaking things further if you are properly grounded when you open the Mac.

I believe bluetooth is controlled by the airport card and shares the airport antenna, but don't have access to definitive hardware manuals to know for sure. It's hard to guess if your issue is hardware or software just from the symptom.

Comment: Thanks for undeleting, I just did so because I thought I did need to research first before asking. But could I clear one thing up...If they airport and camera are the same cable could you guess as to how my camera doesn't work but the wifi does?

Comment: Camera uses different wires in the cable. Could be logic board issue, connector on the board, damage to the cable where it bends around the clutches or most likely a problem on the iSight board itself. Also, don't delete too many questions - you get banned from asking more if too many are deleted..

Comment: So my best bet is have apple check the problem, since replacing the cable my self might not solve it right? Got it, didn't know I could get banned.